# Php sql DISTINCT row id without duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT buyer,caseid,subject,service FROM s_support  
ORDER BY id DESC
```

result is

```
buyer               subject          service    caseid
abel@gmail.com ---- I need help ---- Other ---- 438613
bani@gmail.com ---- Urgent      ---- Other ---- 438612
rony@gmail.com ---- Help        ---- Other ---- 438611
```

I want to view `id` in DISTINCT How? I wants to hide the duplicates to keep only one row per buyer/subject/service/case but keep a row ID.

```
id  buyer               subject          service    caseid
9   abel@gmail.com ---- I need help ---- Other ---- 438613
7   bani@gmail.com ---- Urgent      ---- Other ---- 438612
6   rony@gmail.com ---- Help        ---- Other ---- 438611
```

Comment: cannot understand your question

Comment: how to add id in table views

Comment: The unclear question is : he wants to remove the duplicates to keep only one row per buyer/subject/service/case but keep a row ID. My question is : When you eliminate duplicates, how do you determine which row to keep ? Purely random, last one, first one, or something else?

Comment: Dear @Thomas  thanks i want keep a row ID.that my question

Comment: do you have a column named row id?

Comment: @Fakhruddin yes column is `id`

Comment: @Henok so whats the issue? Select `id` as well in your `select` query.

Comment: can you create a sqlfiddle for the above table schema and share the link.

Comment: @Fakhruddin issue is the second my output table How to make it?

Comment: Sorry I am unable to understand what you are looking to achieve.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Make sure your parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you'll have [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is unclear but you are probably looking for this.

Try both of those in your `mysql_query()` and keep the one that fits your need (if any)

---

Eliminate duplicates and keep the lowest ID

```
     SELECT MIN(id) AS id, buyer,caseid,subject,service 
     FROM s_support 
     GROUP BY buyer,caseid,subject,service
     ORDER BY id DESC
```

---

Eliminate duplicates and keep the highest ID

```
     SELECT MAX(id) AS id, buyer,caseid,subject,service 
     FROM s_support 
     GROUP BY buyer,caseid,subject,service
     ORDER BY id DESC
```

If not, rewrite that question in an intelligible manner :)

Comment: @Henok no issue. Please accept the answer if that's the one you were looking for

Comment: I don't understand. Edit the question and add this at the end

Comment: result show like this `13 - rony@gmail.com - 142523 - help - other - 0` at end zero is `status` column `Max(id)` is 13 but `status` result is not `0` in row. How to get from group in other word multiple column `id` & `status` id use for `max` other `status` is row result @Thomas

Comment: you should add your new column `status` both in the SELECT clause and in the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121752/discussion-between-henok-and-thomas-g).